# How to combine a graph generated with igraph and a plot made with ggplot2 by means of cowplot::plot_grid

Tags: r, ggplot2, igraph, cowplot

Initially, I could not plot it completely, meaning that I could not find a way to capture the plot object and feed it to `cowplot::plot_grid`. Now, I found a workaround which saves to file the image of the graph plot as png and read it with `cowplot::draw_image`. Is there a simpler way to do it? Also, it is difficult to set the parameters of the png in order to have good resolution and size and avoid the margin trimming. I also need some tweaking on the plot, *e.g.*, self-loop and directed arrows with precise values of connection weights should be possible.

In the following, there are two options and their respective results I obtain.

```
library(ggplot2); library(cowplot); library(igraph)
graph_1 <- sample_gnm(10, 25, directed = T, loops = T)
gg_test <- ggplot(data.frame("a" = seq(1, 5, length.out = 10), "b" = runif(10)), aes(x=a, y=b)) + geom_point() + theme_classic()
```

**Option 1 - direct**

```
# option 1 - empty graph
cowplot::plot_grid(plot(graph_1), gg_test)
```

[image: opt1]

**Option 2 - to file**

```
# option 2 - working but horrible code and difficult setting of the resolution/size (r-base not the best)
png("to_delete_for_import.png", res = 150, height = 800, width = 1100)
plot(graph_1, edge.label = LETTERS[1:10], vertex.color = RColorBrewer::brewer.pal(10, "Spectral"))
dev.off()
graph_1_cwpl <- ggdraw() + draw_image("to_delete_for_import.png")
file.remove("to_delete_for_import.png")
cowplot::plot_grid(graph_1_cwpl, gg_test)
```

[image: opt2]

Comment: This does not really work well, but maybe you can find a way of making it better: user `x <- recordPlot()` after you make the graph and then `plot_grid(x, gg_test)`. However, the result is not impressive, I'm afraid. Did you try `ggnet2`?

Comment: `recordPlot()` works but it needs `gridGraphics` package and it is (in my case) adding `NA` labels on the edges. Quality-wise it is fine though! I do not know `ggnet2` I am afraid. I will check it out ;)

Comment: Yeah, the NAs plus messed up node and arrow styles, not sure you can easily deal with that.

Comment: If gridGraphics messes up your plot, please file an issue on github. The goal is to faithfully capture all base graphics, but there are some corner cases that still need fixing.

Comment: I will open the issue. It seems that `ggnet2` (which is quite good) can not handle self-loops that are heavily present in my real application. On the merit, I opened an issue on the GitHub page.

Comment: The issue with `NA`s was recently fixed in gridGraphics: https://github.com/pmur002/gridgraphics/issues/14

Answer (score 2):

I recently had the same issue and found the following solutions to be helpful. The first approach is similar to what user @January already commented:

```
library(ggplotify) 
E(graph_1)$label <- ""
plot_grid(base2grob(~plot(graph_1)),
          gg_test)
```

[image]

And here is the second approach using `ggraph`:

```
library(ggraph)
ggtest2 <- ggraph(graph_1) +
          geom_node_point() +
          geom_edge_link() +
          theme_classic()

plot_grid(ggtest2, gg_test)
```

[image]

Comment: It is not what I am looking for because it still needs to manually silence the labels and I hope there is another way, also considering the number of tools there are for network drawing. Moreover, I do not know how the grob would behave in the case of more complex graph. The same for the second one, but I will take a look if I can improve its aesthetic to the point I need it.